# campo textArea html5

Tags: html, html5, textarea

tengo un campo de texto en html y en la esquina inferior derecha se puede ver como unas rayas para poder hacerlo más grande. no quiero que se haga grande y que tenga un tamaño ya fijo y no movible

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega el siguiente estilo y listo:

```
<style type="text/css">
   textarea 
   {
    resize: none;
   }
</style>

 <textarea name="textarea" ></textarea>
```